# Combinatorics - My teacher and I

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem:** Suppose that after I wrote this problem, my teacher thought he could be more clever than I could, so he wrote his own problem. Suppose that both of our problems are in the set of 12 problems you are currently working on. If you sat down at your computer this morning and randomly loaded 4 of the 12 problems, what is the probability that both this problem and my teacher's problem were among the four you loaded?

I got $\frac{\dbinom{12}{2}}{\dbinom{12}{4}}=2/15,$ because we are choosing 4 out of the 12, but we want to have 2 out of the 12 (meaning there are 2 of our desired outcomes). This is incorrect. Help?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon  If you choose both your problem and your teacher's problem, you must also choose two of the other $10$ problems.  The desired probability is $$\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{12}{4}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 4):

The numerator shouldn't be the "number of things you want to have" if that even makes sense. It should be the total number of choices, *given that you have the things you want to have*.

So, if you want $2$ specific problems to appear, and you're choosing $4$ problems total, then you need to choose the other $2$ problems that appear, out of the $10$ that you haven't already chosen. That means there are $\binom{10}{2}$ options in the numerator, giving $\binom{10}{2}/\binom{12}{4} = \frac1{11}$ as the final answer.